# How to run `tsx` files on a browser directly without compiling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web, deployment

How to run `tsx` files on a browser directly without compiling?

I thought it was impossible before. However recently I found a meta web site https://segment-anything.com/demo which has the `tsx` and `scss` files in the dev tool source.

[image]

And I think it's really running the code since it's in the run stack.

I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Looks like something done by [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). Basically, it changed some file contents into JS before the browser runs it. And if you click on "App.scss" of se-demo, you can even see JS statements.

Comment: If you open `view-source:https://segment-anything.com/`, there is no tsx anywhere. What you can find instead is a script with `src="/js/bundle.e4890985c971a17b3a8a.min.js"`, produced using webpack. It can also produce source maps, so when you debug a .min.js file, you can see the original script even though you run the transformed version.

Answer (score 1):

TSX is just JSX with typing. Typings are ignored by default.

The easiest way to "run `tsx` files on a browser directly" is by including [`<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>`](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx).

This technically does compile, but it's done by the browser.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
  // "HTMLElement" is the typing of TSX
  const elem: HTMLElement = <div>Hello, World!</div>;
  console.log(elem);
</script>
```

For a valid HTML5 page, make sure to add:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>Title</title>
```

Comment: Does this work for an imported `tsx` file?

Comment: @Hao-JungHsieh if you mean `<script src="..." type="text/babel">`, then yes.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you're doing well, Basically, Typescript is the superset of JavaScript, and browsers are not able to understand Typescript directly.
If you want to run typescript code in the browser you want to compile it first.

There are many ways to compile TypeScript. The most common way is to use the TypeScript compiler, which is included in the TypeScript distribution. To compile a TypeScript file.

You can use **ts-node** package to execute TypeScript files from the command line.

Still, if you want to learn about Typescript with a command line kindly follow this link.
https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-execute-the-typescript-file-using-the-command-line

Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Right, but you can host compilers in the browser.