# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at main.tsx:3:1) Getting this error and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: html, typescript, vite

Index.html file

this file just links and opens the main.tsx file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Xumm + Vite + React + TS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/static/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.tsx file

as the comment says In this code snippet, i have set up the basic structure for my React frontend application.

```
// This file is the entrypoint for the frontend.
import  React  from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

I am developeing an app on the XRPL blockchain I am using ionos as my web hoster and when I try to link the main.tsx file into the index.html file it just says Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at main.tsx:3:1) idk why this is happening or what is causing it

Comment: Browsers cannot run Typescript or JSX natively. They need to be _transpiled_ by either a bundler or Babel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run \`tsx\` files on a browser directly without compiling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76285899/how-to-run-tsx-files-on-a-browser-directly-without-compiling)

Comment: I see the VITE logo, what you got in that App.tsx ?

Comment: You're meant to build your Vite app first then deploy the `dist` directory, not the source code

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using VITE.   The only diff I see is that the default VITE setup for react is `<script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>` , hopefully you are running `npm run dev`, and not trying to access index.html directly in a browser.  Check the VITE docs if you are.

Comment: _"not trying to access index.html directly in a browser"_... pretty sure that's exactly what OP is doing